# Copy and Paste a range of data in sheet 1 to another sheet 2 by current date

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA.  Basically I have the following table on sheet 1

[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTGPr.png)

This gets updated daily with # emails we receive depending country / reason for contact.

At the end of the day I would like to assign a macro button that will copy and paste the data to sheet 2 by current date.

[sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf1Tr.png)

Comment: I came here via your related question. So you know: amongst readers, there is an expectation on this site that you try something first, and then you show what you have tried. Whilst some readers do like to prove the theory wrong (see below), in general we are not a free code factory.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a dynamic solution to this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Type EmailData
    us As Object
    ca As Object
End Type

Public Sub RunDataMove()
Dim wsDataFrom As Worksheet
Dim wsDataTo As Worksheet
Dim eData As EmailData
Dim i As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set wsDataFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataFrom") 'Change Worksheet names
    Set wsDataTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataTo") 'Change Worksheet names

    Set eData.us = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set eData.ca = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With wsDataFrom
        For i = 2 To .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
            eData.us.Add .Cells(i, 3).Value, .Cells(i, 1).Value
            eData.ca.Add .Cells(i, 3).Value, .Cells(i, 2).Value
        Next i
    End With

    Call MoveDataByDate(wsDataTo, eData, DateAdd("d", 0, Date)) 'Change add days +/- if needed

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

    MsgBox "Data for " & Date & " has been moved or updated"

End Sub

Public Sub MoveDataByDate(ByRef wsTo As Worksheet, ByRef eData As EmailData, ByVal eDate As Date)
Dim obj As Variant, i As Long, usCol As Long, caCol As Long, dCol As Long, keyName As String
    With wsTo
        For i = 1 To .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
            If .Cells(1, i).Value = eDate Then
                dCol = i
                usCol = i
                caCol = i + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If dCol = 0 And i <> 1 Then
            usCol = i
            caCol = i + 1
        Else
            usCol = 2
            caCol = 3
        End If
        If .Cells(3, 1).Value = "" Then
            i = 3
            For Each obj In eData.us
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = obj
                i = i + 1
            Next obj
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End If
        For i = 3 To .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
            keyName = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            If eData.us.exists(keyName) Then
                .Cells(i, usCol).Value = eData.us(keyName)
            End If
            If eData.ca.exists(keyName) Then
                .Cells(i, caCol).Value = eData.ca(keyName)
            End If
        Next i
        .Cells(1, usCol).Value = eDate
        .Range(.Cells(1, usCol), .Cells(1, caCol)).Merge
        .Cells(2, usCol).Value = "US"
        .Cells(2, caCol).Value = "CA"
        With .Range(.Cells(1, usCol), .Cells(.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, caCol))
            .ColumnWidth = 8
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow I was expecting a reply. Thank you Richard. I will try this out tomorrow at work.

Comment: It works great! TBH I have no idea how this works but thank you again. @RichardBerryhill

Comment: can you edit to the code so that the next  data copy and paste to next empty column. [Please click here for example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NpCHZMOcbayiIgJahBrZrmEvOi20gtnLOkgx8xVnzuw/edit?usp=sharing)